# Determining the XPath of element clicked on in an Android WebView

Tags: java, android, xpath, webview, android-webview

Given a simple webpage loaded in a webview inside an android app, is there a way to determine the XPath of any html element (even a simple paragraph) that the user taps on? Thank you.

Comment: Seems the simplest way to do it is use JavaScript code from an Xpath selector addon for a browser and inject it into the WebView.